# How to hint the index to use in a MySQL select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, hint

I have a MySQL query (running MySQL 5.0.88), which I'm trying to speed up. The underlying table has multiple indices and for the query in question, the wrong index is used (`i_active` - 16.000 rows, vs. `i_iln` - 7 rows).

I'm not very experienced with MySQL but read there is a `use index` hint, which can force mySQL to use a certain index. I'm trying it like this:

```
 SELECT art.firma USE INDEX (i_iln)
 ...
```

but this produces a MySQL error.

**Question**:
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (Except running 5.0.88, which I can't change.)

Comment: For what it's worth, USE INDEX doesn't force the named index to be used. It just means "don't consider using any *other* index." The index you name might be irrelevant to the query, in which case MySQL will still not use it.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You missed the

```sql
FROM table
```

Correct SQL should be:

```sql
SELECT art.firma FROM your_table USE INDEX (i_iln) WHERE ....
```

Comment: ah... 2100ms to 0ms. Cool!

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from table use index (idx);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 3):

sometimes, with **use index (index_name)** optimizer might go for table scan, if you use hint **force index**, optimizer will be forced to use index, will go for table scan only if no ways left to get the rows with provided index.

```
SELECT art.firma FROM art FORCE INDEX (i_iln);
```

for more detail on hints **USE INDEX** and **FORCE INDEX** check this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Coloumn1, Coloumn2, Coloumn.... FROM TABLE_NAME USE INDEX (index_name) WHERE Coloumn = "condition";
```

If you have the correct index, you don't need to use index(). Your query automatically selects the correct index. If your query is slow after using the index then recheck your index, something wrong in the index.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from some editing towards readability, some formatting and some deleting of texts fragments which look like unused template placeholders.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.